# How simultaneity of same event in time dilation works?

Tags: special-relativity, time, time-dilation

If an event has happened in space and that same event is observed from two different frame of references in one frame it takes more time to happen than other when observed(Time dilation). Now because that same event is observed will that be actually physically synchronised? If the events are not synchronised then how two copies of same event are created which are happening at different rates?
Consider an instant while event was happening (same event mentioned above) and at that particular instant will the observations made from two frames be same ?

Answer (score 1):

You should not think of there being separate 'copies' of an event in different reference frames- there is only one physical event.

Suppose you play a game of chess on a moving train. You start the game as you pass a station at which the clock says it is 4pm. You set your own watch to 4pm as you go by. You finish the game as you pass another station where the clock says it is 5pm. If your train is travelling at about 0.8c relative to the stations, you will think the game lasted about 30 minutes by your watch, and that the clock at the second station must be out of synch with the first.

There is only one game of chess. To you it lasted 30 minutes- to the people at the stations it seems to have lasted an hour. From their perspective, the reason for the discrepancy is that your watch is running slower than their clocks; from your perspective, the reason for the discrepancy is that their clocks are out of synch.

Comment: Suppose when I was playing chess in that train I had touched point A on chess board at a particular instant and someone from outside of train is watching me at that particular instant when I touched point A on chess board then will he be able to see that I actually touched chess board at the same instant? As the flow of time was different for both of us?

Comment: Obviously, yes. People don’t turn invisible if they set their watch wrong. I just see that they have a different number on their watch than I do.

Comment: "You should not think of there being separate 'copies' of an event in different reference frames- there is only one physical event". But why not if an event occurs at different pace for two different observers then surely that event is not synchronised as observed by other person as relativity is physically true then it means both the observers are observing what actually physically is happening. (it's just maybe like shooting a video and play it at 0.5x or any other speed and comparing it at same time with original one. Obviously both will not be synchronised) .i.e. present and future

Comment: It is one physical event that's why it contradicts relativity

Comment: Try to remember that all observers agree that a given event occurs at exactly the same place in spacetime- they simply disagree on what values of x,y,z and t to use to label the position of the event.  So if there are two events, namely the start and the end of your chess game, everyone agrees about where they each happen in spacetime, but they label them differently because they use different x,y,z and t coordinate systems.